# How to statically store and call a node.js callback function

Tags: node.js, windows, callback, add-on

I have a node.js addon that I developped for node 0.10 and I need to update it for the current node. I fixed most of the api changes but I'm stuck with the issue of storing a callback pointer statically for later call. I modified 3_callback example addon to show what I did so far and the error I get during compile. This is what I have so far (the compile error is added as commented lines):

```
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

typedef Persistent<Function> CallBack_t;

static CallBack_t MyCallBack;

void CallBack( char* str ) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope( isolate );

  const unsigned argc = 1;
  Local<Value> argv[ argc ] = { String::NewFromUtf8( isolate, str ) };
  Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::New( isolate, MyCallBack );
  cb->Call( isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv );
}

void RunCallback( const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args ) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope( isolate );

  Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast( args[ 0 ] );
  MyCallBack = CallBack_t::New( isolate, cb );
  //..\addon.cc( 24 ) : error C2664 : 'v8::Function *v8::PersistentBase<T>::New(v8::Isolate *,T *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'v8::Local<v8::Function>' to 'v8::Function *' [E:\SoftwareProjects\node-addon-examples\trunk\3_global_callback\node_0.12\build\addon.vcxproj]
  //   with
  //   [
  //      T = v8::Function
  //   ]
  //..\addon.cc( 24 ) : note : No user - defined - conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called  CallBack( "JavaScriptCallBack calling" );
}

void Init( Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module ) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD( module, "exports", RunCallback );
}

NODE_MODULE( addon, Init )
```

I tried different alternative but none works so far. Where is the error?

Comment: Tip: you should use [`nan`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) for better compatibility across v8 versions. `nan` also handles a lot of other things behind the scenes, especially when it comes to calling callbacks (such as making sure it's called within the appropriate active domain in case of a thrown exception).

Comment: Thanks mscdex for the suggestion. I could modify the addon so it builds and execute using nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Addressing the error in your code:**

`cannot convert argument 2 from 'v8::Local<v8::Function>' to 'v8::Function *'`

This should fix it:

```
v8::Local<v8::Function> cb = std::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
v8::Function * f_ptr = *cb;
```

.

**For Statically Storing and Calling a JS-Callback Function in Node V8 Version 4.X.X:**
*callbacks.cxx:*

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> r_call;

/** Save the JS-Callback for later use.
 *  If args[0] is not a function (such as null), remove callback
 */
void RunCallback(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    if (args[0]->IsFunction()) {
        v8::Local<v8::Function> func = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
        v8::Function * ptr = *func;
        r_call.Reset(isolate, func);
    }
    else {
        r_call.Reset();
    }
}

/* Run the saved callback if there is one. */
void run() {
    if(!r_call.IsEmpty()) {
        v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
        v8::Local<v8::Function> func = v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(isolate, r_call);

        if (!func.IsEmpty()) {
            const unsigned argc = 1;
            v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] =
                { v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello world") };
            func->Call(v8::Null(isolate), argc, argv);
        }
    }
}
```

*test.js:*

```
const mod = require("...");
mod.RunCallback((msg) => { console.log(msg); });
mod.run();
```

<sub>*-- tested with: node-gyp v4.4.4, MSVS2013, SWIGv3.0.10 --*</sub>

Comment: What a coincidence. I was just getting back to this project after a few months off. I will try your code as I would like to avoid the NAN dependency. Thanks.

Comment: So that worked very well. I marked your answer as useful... Oups, I can't. I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: (You however don't need reputation to mark it as correct. If this is the answer you were looking for, you should mark this as correct so others may also find it.)

Comment: Marked it as correct. Late, I know but done. Many thanks.

Comment: Tthis trick also works to save and reuse js classes defined in C++ (function templates with prototype methods, accessors, etc.  It saved my bacon when I could not get node::ObjectWrap (or Nan::ObjectWrap) to bend to my will, eliminating scads of boilerplate integration code in the process.